# What's wrong with my java code?(whileloop)

Tags: java

So I've been learning Java i have stumbled across a problem, could anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 0;
    int grade;
    int average = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter>10) {
        grade = input.nextInt();
        total += grade;
        counter++;
    }
     average = total/10;
        System.out.print("avg is: "+ aveg);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 while (counter>10)    //  while(0>10) ---> while(false){//Not executed}
```

while condition is not true because count is zero so while body is not executed

instead do

```
while (counter<10)
```

and also put your code inside function because in java nothing except declaration and initialization done outside the function

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

//only declaration and initialization outside methods

public static void main(String a[]){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 0;
    int grade;
    int average = 0;
    int counter = 0; 

    while (counter<10) {
        grade = input.nextInt();
        total += grade;
        counter++;
    }
        average = total/10;
        System.out.print("avg is: "+ average);
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/tOAw8K)

Comment: Okay but i still get errors such as unexpected token in the while loop and unknown classes. Here is a screenshot: http://gyazo.com/484cfd2fcc40979243747db46b71bb08

Answer (score 0):

Also in your code, you're not even checking whether there's a next int value by using the `hasNextInt` method.

your while loop won't work because you're testing for `counter>10` while `counter = 0` to begin with , so it won't even enter in the while loop

apart from your while loop issue, methinks you should modify your code like this

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 0;
    int grade;
    int average = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter>10) {
      if(input.hasNextInt()){ 
             //this line is important , 
             //else code will throw an exception if no more input is found next
        grade = input.nextInt();
        total += grade;
        counter++;
      }
    }
     average = total/10;
        System.out.print("avg is: "+ aveg);
}
```